# Are there infinite many numbers that are the difference of two permutations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, permutations

The permutations of $459$ are:

{$459, 495, 549, 594, 945, 954$}

and the difference of $954$ and $495$ is $459$ itself.

I'm considering only numbers without the digit $0$ to avoid trivial ones such as $4590, 45900, 459000$, etc.

Using this python script:

```
def int_permutations(x):
    # return the permutations of a positive integer
    # >>> int_permutations(123)
    # [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
    from itertools import permutations
    digits = list(str(x))
    perms = permutations(digits)
    perms = ["".join(perm) for perm in perms]
    perms = [int(perm) for perm in perms]
    return perms


def permutation_pairs(x):
    # list the permutations in pairs
    perms = int_permutations(x)
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(perms)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(perms)):
            pairs.append((perms[i], perms[j]))
    return pairs


def difference_pair(x):
    # return two permutations of x
    # that the difference of them is equal to x
    # if x can't be represented that way, return None
    perm_pair = None
    for perm1, perm2 in permutation_pairs(x):
        difference = abs(perm1 - perm2)
        if difference == x:
            perm_pair = (perm1, perm2)
            perm_pair = sorted(perm_pair, reverse=True)
            break
    return perm_pair



n = 1
while True:
    pair = difference_pair(n)
    if pair is not None and "0" not in str(n):
        print(f"{n} = {pair[0]} - {pair[1]}")
    n += 1
```

I could find some more numbers with this property:

```
459 = 954 - 495
495 = 954 - 459
1269 = 2961 - 1692
1467 = 7614 - 6147
1476 = 6147 - 4671
1692 = 2961 - 1269
1746 = 6417 - 4671
2385 = 5238 - 2853
2439 = 4932 - 2493
2493 = 4932 - 2439
2538 = 5823 - 3285
2691 = 9612 - 6921
2853 = 5238 - 2385
3285 = 5823 - 2538
4392 = 9324 - 4932
4599 = 9594 - 4995
4671 = 6417 - 1746
4698 = 9684 - 4986
4797 = 9774 - 4977
4896 = 9864 - 4968
4932 = 9324 - 4392
4959 = 9954 - 4995
4968 = 9864 - 4896
4977 = 9774 - 4797
4986 = 9684 - 4698
4995 = 9954 - 4959
5238 = 8523 - 3285
5382 = 8235 - 2853
6147 = 7614 - 1467
6174 = 7641 - 1467
6921 = 9612 - 2691
12348 = 24831 - 12483
12375 = 37512 - 25137
12384 = 34218 - 21834
12429 = 24921 - 12492
12438 = 34281 - 21843
12456 = 54612 - 42156
12465 = 54621 - 42156
12483 = 24831 - 12348
12492 = 24921 - 12429
12537 = 35712 - 23175
12564 = 54126 - 41562
12654 = 54216 - 41562
12699 = 29691 - 16992
12834 = 34218 - 21384
12843 = 34281 - 21438
12897 = 92178 - 79281
12969 = 29961 - 16992
12987 = 91278 - 78291
13248 = 31482 - 18234
13428 = 34812 - 21384
13482 = 28314 - 14832
13725 = 31257 - 17532
13752 = 31275 - 17523
13824 = 32148 - 18324
13842 = 32184 - 18342
13986 = 83169 - 69183
14238 = 32481 - 18243
14256 = 56412 - 42156
14265 = 56421 - 42156
14283 = 38421 - 24138
14292 = 29214 - 14922
14328 = 38142 - 23814
14382 = 32814 - 18432
14562 = 56124 - 41562
...
```

Are there infinite many of those?

Comment: Do 405+045=450 and 450+054=504 count?

Comment: And do they need to count? We already have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Even without allowing terminal zeroes there are still infinitely many. You can concatenate solutions. If $\color{blue}{954-495=459}$ and $\color{brown}{7641-1467=6174}$, then $\color{blue}{954}\color{brown}{7641}-\color{blue}{495}\color{brown}{1467}=\color{blue}{459}\color{brown}{6174}$.